# How to move the numerical calculation part from VHDL code to C can run it on NEXY3 Spartan 6 board

Tags: c, vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise, spartan

I am currently working on a project which requires to use a embedded soft core. I wrote a pong game using VHDL (ISE) and synthesised it onto the FPGA, the next step is going to shift the numerical calculation part to soft core which means i need to rewirte this code in C. However, ISE can not achieve this function, what design suite (software) i can use? Can EDK work?

Comment: Why you don´t use Xilinx [HLS](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/integration/esl-design.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a soft processor to your project using EDK and synthesize the new project. Then you can write the software code to run on the soft processor using SDK (Software Development Kit).